# Detect/update Python2-style code that is no longer needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I maintain a moderately big open source project (~22000 lines of python code)

Because it has been in development for a long time and was originally written for Python 2 there is a lot of unnecessarily complex code. Code that could be simplified (and unified) by using modern Python 3 syntax (for example meta-classes, which have significantly simpler syntax nowadays).

Is there some established way to do this? At least detect python2-isms (maybe using pylint and some specific settings?), but ideally auto-correct them.

If possible, I want the code to refrain from "Python <3.6-isms" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) and [pyupgrade](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade).

You can top things off with [`flynt`](https://pypi.org/project/flynt/) for f-string conversion.

From my shell history:

```
pyupgrade --py36-plus $(git ls-files '*.py')
flynt $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

Comment: Awesome. 2to3 doesnt really help much (running it on already-python3-compatible code just makes it worse), but pyupgrade and flynt seem to be exactly the kind of things I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there are some established ways to convert between -isms, as it depends a lot on the use case and such.

There are some scripts to convert Python2 code to Python3, like [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html), but it does not consider everything you want to do.